# Keras Tensorflow error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, python-3.5

I am trying to run the jupyter notebook. But getting error in executing the following code:

```
data_gen_test = dl.generate_clean_data(
    configs['data']['filename_clean'],
    batch_size=configs['data']['batch_size'],
    start_index=ntrain
)

ntest = nrows - ntrain
steps_test = int(ntest / configs['data']['batch_size'])
print('> Testing model on', ntest, 'data rows with', steps_test, 'steps')

predictions = model.predict_generator(
    generator_strip_xy(data_gen_test, true_values),
    steps=steps_test
)

#Save our predictions
with h5py.File(configs['model']['filename_predictions'], 'w') as hf:
    dset_p = hf.create_dataset('predictions', data=predictions)
    dset_y = hf.create_dataset('true_values', data=true_values)

plot_results(predictions[:800], true_values[:800])
```

The error I encounter:

```
> Testing model on 36122 data rows with 361 steps
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1063             subfeed_t = self.graph.as_graph_element(subfeed, allow_tensor=True,
-> 1064                                                     allow_operation=False)
   1065           except Exception as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in as_graph_element(self, obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
   3034     with self._lock:
-> 3035       return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
   3036 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _as_graph_element_locked(self, obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
   3113       if obj.graph is not self:
-> 3114         raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
   3115       return obj

ValueError: Tensor Tensor("lstm_1_input:0", shape=(?, ?, 4), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2b74f10ce00c> in <module>()
     11 predictions = model.predict_generator(
     12     generator_strip_xy(data_gen_test, true_values),
---> 13     steps=steps_test
     14 )
     15 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     85                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     86                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 87             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     88         wrapper._original_function = func
     89         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/models.py in predict_generator(self, generator, steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, verbose)
   1302                                             workers=workers,
   1303                                             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
-> 1304                                             verbose=verbose)
   1305 
   1306     def get_config(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     85                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     86                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 87             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     88         wrapper._original_function = func
     89         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in predict_generator(self, generator, steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, verbose)
   2423                     x = generator_output
   2424 
-> 2425                 outs = self.predict_on_batch(x)
   2426                 if not isinstance(outs, list):
   2427                     outs = [outs]

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in predict_on_batch(self, x)
   1900             ins = x
   1901         self._make_predict_function()
-> 1902         outputs = self.predict_function(ins)
   1903         if len(outputs) == 1:
   1904             return outputs[0]

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2355         session = get_session()
   2356         updated = session.run(fetches=fetches, feed_dict=feed_dict,
-> 2357                               **self.session_kwargs)
   2358         return updated[:len(self.outputs)]
   2359 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    887     try:
    888       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 889                          run_metadata_ptr)
    890       if run_metadata:
    891         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1065           except Exception as e:
   1066             raise TypeError('Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: '
-> 1067                             + e.args[0])
   1068 
   1069           if isinstance(subfeed_val, ops.Tensor):

TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("lstm_1_input:0", shape=(?, ?, 4), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

Here is the complete Jupyter notebook:  [Notebook](https://gist.github.com/ubaidsworld/a3b2770b09383fba7eadf8c4326441b4)

I am usiing the latest version of Tensorflow 1.4.1 and Keras 2.1.2

Comment: can anyone help me please.

Comment: Can you please provide both your Tensorflow version and Keras version?

Comment: @Tay2510 Updated question with the version Tensorflow 1.4.1 and Keras 2.1.2

Comment: Can anyone help me with this issue, please?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. did you find a fix?

Comment: @Scratch No didn't. If you get then please let me know.

Comment: I was using keras. I solved my problem running 
import keras
keras.backend.clear_session()
but it's probably not related to your case.

Comment: @Scratch I tried it and it wasn't working.